# Как отловить переключение фрагмента ViewPager'а внутри фрагмента?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

У меня есть ViewPager с фрагментами. Внутри фрагмента есть плеер. Мне нужно остановить плеер, если пользователь переключил фрагмент с текущего на другой. Как мне отловить переключение (или перелистывание) фрагмента внутри самого фрагмента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите метод фрагмента, который вызывается при смене видимости фрагмента юзеру. **Будьте осторожны** - сей метод **может** вызываться ещё **до создания разметки** фрагмента.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
{
    Log.d("TAG", "setUserVisibleHint isVisibleToUser: " + isVisibleToUser);
    if(!isVisibleToUser)
    {
        //тут фрагмент более не виден юзеру,
        //т.е. в нашем случае фрагмент был пролистан
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает

Comment: Как всегда очень точно) Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Если что-то сложное и связано с событиями между компонентами - пользуйся EventBus. Но лучше не перебарщивать.